# Linux mkdir to make directories with serial number

Tags: linux

In my CentOS-7, I want to create some directories with names, say *name001*, *name002*, ... *name003*.

How to do this without typing
`mkdir name001` `mkdir name002`
and so on?

Comment: `mkdir name00{1..3}`

Comment: @Barmar: Is this the only one solution?

Comment: You can also use a `for` or `while` loop. Lots of ways that should be obvious to anyone who knows shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the echo, if you are happy with the output

```
for i in $(seq -s " " -f %03g 1 10); do echo mkdir name${i}; done
```